# Can't figure out this Trig. proof: $ \cos(x+y)\cos (x-y)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(y)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(y)$$

I use the sum and difference formula to reduce the right hand side of the equation to $$[\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)][\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)]$$  then foil to end up with $$\cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)-\sin^2(x)\sin^2(y)$$ and I can't see what to do from here any help? I know it's really simple but I can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: Do you mean the left hand side?

Comment: The equation written is not an identity.

Comment: @ mickep The RHS should read $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(y)$, I presume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:
Notice,

$$LHS=\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)=(\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y)(\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y)$$
$$=(\cos x\cos y)^2-(\sin x\sin y)^2$$
$$=\cos^2 x\cos^2 y-\sin^2 x\sin^2 y$$
$$=\cos^2 x(1-\sin^2 y)-(1-\cos^2 x)\sin^2 y$$
$$=\cos^2 x-\cos^2 x\sin^2 y-\sin^2 y+\cos^2 x\sin^2 y$$
$$=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 y$$

Comment: That is quite a "HINT."